# onListItemClick + android

Tags: android, listview

Can you explain this method's parameters?  I did not understand them. 
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#setListAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29)

```
 onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
```

`ListView l`: defines the ListView on which the click event is happening?

`View v`: defines the view that was clicked within the ListView?  So for a ListView, that would be the xml containing the ListView, and if its a custom ListView the xml containing the row?

`int position`: The position of the view in the list. Can it be retrieved using below function?  `getListView().getPositionForView((LinearLayout)v.getParent())`

`long id`: The row id of the item that was clicked. Is this not same as `position`?  Or do we provide R.id.Textview?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859910/android-adapterview-click-listener-parameters-position-id

Answer (score 1):

Its simple.

ListView l --> Is the name of the listview object on which the click is happening. (Simple)

Like

```
ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

View v ---> There can be multiple view inside a list view. So this tells that which of the view has been clicked and takes action accordingly.

Position --> The position of the view in the list. (VIEW POSITION)

id  ---> Row id of the ITEM . (ITEM ID)

Comment: Soumil Deshpande so how do we obtain the view that has been clicked??

Comment: getSelectedItemPosition()

Answer (score 1):

A  listview consists of small items/rows. While using  a custom listView. Each row/item can have different functionality and layout. so for each row/item we must use different functionality..

For example in a listview at the fourth row there is a button while on all other items there is only text. So in order to put your event there you must get that particular row/item contents. the below code gives you the access to single item..

```
 onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 


first parameter is parent where the click happened

second parameter is single View(child/row) of a ListView(Parent)

third parameter is the position of child view.

fourth parameter is the id of the child view.
```

Answer (score 0):

1-first one ListView Object that one you define by :

```
ListView foo = (ListView) findViewbyId(R.id.foo);
```

2-second Row item it self (View v) one is simple that's object you click on (you can obtain the view that has been clicked), you can change color or content or what ever you want

3-position index of (View  v) object in ListView start from 0

4- Row id of item (i never have been used)